# TkInter install using "easy Install"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi i'm trying to write some project with a friend of mine using Cloud9.
In my project i need the module TkInter.
Cloud9 supports easyInstall.

Does anyone know how to install tkinter in cloud9 or at least where to get the package for easyInstall?

Comment: What is so specific on cloud9? I am asking, because `Tkinter` is standard Python library and should be preinstalled. Also note that the name is `Tkinter` in Python 2.x but `tkinter` in Python 3.x.

Comment: It allows us to edit the code on distance(over internet), instantly seeing each others code, and has build-in shell.

Comment: So the interpreter is installed on server and you access it through a web page?

Comment: Yes the shell is included and i can run the code from the browser using python someFile.py.

Comment: Well, it looks to me that if `tkinter` is not included they have a good reason for it. How would you expect to run desktop GUI application through your web browser?

Comment: I didn't think this through. I don't know internet technology so well. Maybe it opens a local java applet? So you think this is non doable...

Comment: Even if it is interesting idea, I do not think that Cloud9 supports something like that. But you can learn some web programming instead. Like Flask, Django, etc.